# Prevalence of Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFs as standard for online maps

Tags: web-mapping, web-service, cloud-optimized-geotiff

OpenLayers is the only JavaScript library I have found so far that supports Cloud Optimized GeoTIFFS out of the box.

Is it common practice to expose data simply as a Cloud Optimized GeoTIFF without any other webservices like WMS,WMTS, etc.?

I'd be particularly interested if you have hard data showing usage. So far, all services I found online offer the regular WMS, WMTS, etc. but I do not have any actual data or source on this apart from my observations.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.